# Getorgchart, get id of edited node?

Tags: getorgchart

How can I get the id of an edited node in a function - updatedEvent () ?

```js
        function updatedEvent(sender, args) {
            var model = [];
            for (var id in orgChart.nodes) {
                var node = orgChart.nodes[id];
                var data = $.extend(true, { Id: node.id, ParentId: node.pid }, node.data);
                model.push(data);
            }

            var model = JSON.stringify({ 'model': model });
        }
```

Comment: <!-- begin snippet: js hide: false console: true babel: false -->

<!-- language: lang-js -->

            var peopleElement = document.getElementById("people");
            var orgChart = new getOrgChart(peopleElement, {
                ...
                updatedEvent: updatedEvent};



            function updatedEvent(sender, args) {
               ...
               console.log('updatedEvent, args='+args);
            }


<!-- end snippet -->

Console:   updatedEvent, args=undefined

Answer (score 0):

You can use [updateNodeEvent](http://www.getorgchart.com/Documentation#updateNodeEvent) instead

Comment: I use it. But the arguments are not passed there.